# Empty [intellectual-property]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I propose to empty [intellectual-property] because it's an overly generic tag and all the questions in it can be moved to more specific existing tags. Additionally, [there is no tag wiki yet](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/intellectual-property/info).

There are in particular the following possible targets:

- https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/copyright/info (most questions belong here)
- https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/patents/info (a few questions belong here; the tag wiki doesn't tell otherwise, so this seems to be about both ownership and inventor attribution/"authorship" of the invention)
- https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/authorship/info (apparently only as relating to copyright)
- https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/plagiarism/info (apparently only as relating to copyright)

Answer (score 2):

There *are* general questions in [intellectual-property](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) that don't fit in any of the more specific tags. For example, [What level of sponsor ownership is normal for an industry-sponsored research project?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52043/what-level-of-sponsor-ownership-is-normal-for-an-industry-sponsored-research-pro) and [PhD student, issued contract at year 3 which will sign over intellectual property. Is it legal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/phd-student-issued-contract-at-year-3-which-will-sign-over-intellectual-propert).

I am not in favor of eliminating [intellectual-property](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property).